# Placing Spring @Sql file next to test class in source directories

Tags: maven, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I'm trying to use the `@Sql` annotation in my tests. It’s supposed to find the `.sql` files in the same package as the test, but it's not working for me with Maven. Maven isn't copying the file to the same place it's compiling the `.class` file. If I manually copy the file there, then it works.

How do I get maven to copy the file for me? Thanks.

Comment: `@Sql` searches via the class path. You should put your sql files into `src/test/resources`...

Comment: It also searches in the package (if you specify it as "file.sql"). I prefer that, so I can keep the SQL next to the test, rather than putting dozens of SQL files in resources.

Comment: The issue is that you have them in `src/test/java/<package>/XYZTest.java` and `src/test/java/<package>/abc.sql`  which means the SQL files will not being copied to any location cause `src/test/java` is intended only for Java files. I you like having it associated best is to `src/test/resources/<package>/*.sql`  than they will be copied to the correct locations and are bing available on the classpath....

Comment: Is there really no way to tell Maven to copy the files?

Comment: You can of course, but that violates **convention over configuration** paradigm. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html  (I strongly discourage this way). And what is the problem with having the SQL files in your resources directory where they belong?

Comment: They won't appear next to the corresponding test files in the IDE.

Comment: I can just type a shortcut in my IDE to jump to the corresponding SQL file if I need to. To be honest I don't see that problem. But of course it's up to you....Apart from that how many sql files do you have ?

Comment: I don't want to have to do that. I want to see it right there, next to the class it belongs with. I shouldn't have to go hunting through my hierarchy to find it.